# Regex pattern for a number and letter combination in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble with my regex for finding all directories with a number and letter in the title.

Basically in `//"E:\SomeProvider\SomeGame\build\images\1136x640\img.png"`
I am looking for an output of `//"1136x640"`

Comment: *"I'm having trouble with my regex"* Would you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54401700/edit) your question and add your regex?

Comment: You should add some more examples or add a better issue definietion: `with a number and letter in the title` is too unspecific. You should add some not matching examples as well. And you should add your tested Regex(es) as well, so we can better understand, what you are/wer thinking

Answer (score 1):

Without a better set of examples or explanation, this is the best regex I can think of:

`[^\\/]*(?:[a-zA-Z][^\\/]*\d|\d[^\\/]*[a-zA-Z])[^\\/]*`

Basically it matches everything that is not `\` or `/` that contains a letter and a number after, or vice versa.

You can see a more detailed explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/0exYUQ/3) and test your own examples.